# R- Using loop to combine logit regression and association rules

Tags: r, logistic-regression, apriori

I know I'm missing something in my understanding of logistic regression, and would really appreciate any help.

I have built a logit model and I can compute the predicted probability by
entering "top", "bottom", "right", "left' by hand, see below :

```
    >QPI<-read.csv("QPI_combine2.csv")
    >spec_q2<-glm(result ~ Top + Right + Left + Bottom + I(Top^2) + I(Left^2) + 
                 I(Bottom^2) + Top:Right + Top:Bottom + Right:
    >test_predict <- with(QPI, data.frame(Top=54,Bottom=-48,Right=17,Left=-20))
    >test_predict$prob<-predict(spec_q2, newdata=test_predict,type="response")
    >test_predict
      Top Bottom Right Left      prob
   1  54    -48    17  -20 0.9117354
```

and I also used apriori algorithm to get 26 rows of combinations of "top", "bottom", "right", "left', my question is that is it possible to loop these all in the logit regression model to compute the probability automatically.

```
    >rules_both<-apriori(QPI2, control = list(verbose=F), 
            parameter=list(minlen=5, supp=0.001, conf=0.01),
            appearance = list(rhs=c("PASS=1","PASS=0"),
                              default="lhs"))

    >rules2.sorted<-sort(rules_both, by="lift")
    >as(rules2.sorted, "data.frame")

                                           rules             support confidence lift
    1  {Top=59,Bottom=-51,Right=15,Left=-19} => {PASS=0} 0.001071429          1  3.5
    2  {Top=57,Bottom=-52,Right=17,Left=-24} => {PASS=0} 0.001071429          1  3.5
    5  {Top=51,Bottom=-54,Right=15,Left=-24} => {PASS=0} 0.001071429          1  3.5
    11 {Top=52,Bottom=-53,Right=15,Left=-23} => {PASS=0} 0.001428571          1  3.5
    14 {Top=53,Bottom=-49,Right=16,Left=-22} => {PASS=0} 0.001071429          1  3.5
    16 {Top=48,Bottom=-54,Right=16,Left=-20} => {PASS=0} 0.001071429          1  3.5
    19 {Top=52,Bottom=-54,Right=17,Left=-22} => {PASS=0} 0.001428571          1  3.5
    24 {Top=48,Bottom=-50,Right=14,Left=-22} => {PASS=0} 0.001428571          1  3.5
```

I've stored the combinations in "data"as data frame and then pass to the newdata arguments but seems in vain.

```
    >data<-as(rules2.sorted, "data.frame")
    >test_predict$prob<-predict(spec_q2, newdata=data,type="response")
     Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "prob", value = c(0.972014164301877,  : 
     replacement has 2800 rows, data has 1
     In addition: Warning message:
     'newdata' had 26 rows but variables found have 2800 rows
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, you need to create a data.frame from your `rules2.sorted` (columns as those used in the model) and pass that to `newdata` argument in predict.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik: I've assigned it as data frame and passed to the argments in predict. Kindly see my update. Thanks.